# "the esperanto of switches"

Tags: metaphors

A user made a comment [on my question here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/43250/is-there-a-better-way-to-design-switches-than-i-o/74033#comment65978_43264):

> O and I are the esperanto of switches: they're made for everyone, but
>   only experts understand them.

The definition of *esperanto*, according to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/esperanto) is:

- an artificial international language based as far as possible on words common to the chief European languages

So I don't exactly understand the context of using *"esperanto"* in that comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esperanto was created to be a language of equality, equally easy to learn for people of any linguistic background. It was meant to be universal, being used equally all over the world. (It's neither, of course: it's heavily biased against people with non-Indo-European language backgrounds, and it's also mostly used in Europe and North America. But equality was the intention.)

It failed in becoming a commonly used language of the world, though, and is currently only really used and understood by a small minority of people who have learnt it because of what it stands for, more than because of its actual usefulness.

The same can be said for a 0/1 or O/I switch: it's meant to be international and understood by everybody because it uses a metalinguistic symbolism which is the same all over the world—but the symbolism is only known to a minority of people familiar with binary representation.

Like Esperanto, it will be understood equally well all over the world—but like Esperanto, that really means it will be understood equally *poorly* everywhere in the world.

Comment: But there is a vast panoply of international symbols alive and thriving in the world today which people of all languages understand to some degree. I have never heard them described metaphorically as *Esperanto* symbols, but it seems a good enough name for me. Sine the word *Esperanto* means *hope* in its own language, perhaps we should all try and promote it as a description of internationally accepted typography.